# How to specify the charset when connecting to a MySQL server with ExpressJS?

Tags: mysql, express, encoding, mojibake, charset

I am using the MySQL npm package to connect via Express to my MySQL database, however I would like to specify `utf8mb4` as the charset for this connection, however I can't find anything in the docs about how to do this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is that related to node.js??  If so, consider `var connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... , charset : 'utf8mb4'});`